# What is the "mood" you are in when you shake your head called?

Tags: word-request, vocabulary

You see that somebody just cannot figure out how to open a new tab (something you find easy) and you shake your head. What is this mood or feeling called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might feel 'Frustrated' by the other person's poor grasp of what, to you, is a simple concept...

> frustrated frʌˈstreɪtɪd/ adjective adjective: frustrated
>
> ```
> 1.feeling or expressing distress and annoyance resulting from an inability to change or achieve something.
> "young people get frustrated with the system"
> ```